# Relation between an Object life cycle and method calls from a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, oop

I'm new to OOP and I'm having some doubts regarding the relation between an instantiated object and a method call via webpage.

Ex. I have an object with a method that appends an element in to the webpage as follow:

```
var Elm = function (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

Elm.prototype.insert = function () {
  let img = document.createElement("img");
  img.id = "pic1";
  img.src = "http://someurl.com/images/pic.png";
  img.style.position = 'absolute';
  img.style.left = this.x + "px";
  img.style.top = this.y + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(img);
};

Elm.prototype.move = function (x,y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
};

function img_insert(x,y) {
  var pic = new Elm(x, y);
  pic.insert();
}

function img_move(x,y) {
  img.move(x,y);
}
```

Then in the html I have 2 buttons, one calls the img_insert and the second calls img_move. Even though I follow the order by first calling img_insert and then img_move. The second will not work.

After I call the 1st function img_insert, the end result will be a 'physical' elm on the webpage and the way I understand my object is gone after the code leaves the function. And what's wrong is that the 2nd function: img_move is not really about manipulation the already dead object, but actually about manipulation of the DOM by getting the img by id and changing x and y style attributes, right?

I know how to do the DOM manipulation, my doubt is actually about the code design and its relation to the webpage. Thanks in advance for the input.

Comment: If you want to keep the object around, you have to store in some (global) variable or data structure where `img_move` can access it. Also you'd need a reference from the `Elm` instance to the DOM element, so that the `move` method can update it.

Comment: Hum, but again having global vars, may not be a good design. I believe, considering it's code to interact with a webpage. The 1st step is OOP and the 2nd, it's pure DOM manipulation.???
Also considering that after the 1st button click, the img will be already on the webpage anyways. For the 1nd button just get the html elm and change its style attributes. Instead of going back to the code in the Class/Object model???

Comment: But that's what you will get when you call into two global functions from from the global event handlers of the global buttons… Of course you could encapsulate all of this so that it is no longer global.

Comment: Not sure what distinction you make between "OOP" and "pure DOM manipulation"? They could be one and the same. And yes, you could consider just getting the html element and change its style attributes, but then you wouldn't need your `Elm` instance at all any more.

Comment: I thought that after the 1st btn click, the Elm instance would be gone. Actually that was my main doubt and as I understood the browser will keep that alive until I close the page?

Comment: No, your `Elm` instance indeed is gone (the local `pic` variable goes out of scope when the function ends, and nothing else references it any longer), and that's exactly the problem. You wouldn't need any OOP for that approach at all, just make a procedure that inserts the image into the document. Keeping the object around for later (e.g. in the global `pic` variable in @Morphyish's answer)  is what allows you to structure your data properly.

Comment: If I consider that the Elm will be always an image, is it right to move the following lines from the insert method to the constructor?

  this.img = document.createElement("img");
  this.img.style.position = 'absolute';
  this.img.style.left = this.x + "px";
  this.img.style.top = this.y + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(this.img);

and only keep:

this.img.id = "pic1";
  this.img.src = "http://nostarch.com/images/car.png";

in the insert method, considering I will change  id and img.src for evry button click?

Comment: Yes, creating the `<img>` element and storing it in the `this.img` property should be done in the constructor. Assigning the style one might do in an extra method, as you'll probably have to do that in the `move` method as well. The line `document.body.appendChild(this.img)` definitely should stay in the `insert` method.

Answer (score 0):

The `move` method is update the `x` and `y` properties of `Elm`. However they are not updating the style of the img.

Try something like

```
var Elm = function (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

Elm.prototype.insert = function () {
  this.img = document.createElement("img");
  this.img.id = "pic1";
  this.img.src = "http://someurl.com/images/pic.png";
  this.img.style.position = 'absolute';
  this.img.style.left = this.x + "px";
  this.img.style.top = this.y + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(this.img);
};

Elm.prototype.move = function (x,y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.img.style.left = this.x + "px";
  this.y += y;
  this.img.style.top = this.y + "px";
};

var pic;

function img_insert(x,y) {
  pic = new Elm(x, y);
  pic.insert();
}

function img_move(x,y) {
  pic.move(x,y);
}
```

Comment: The code breaks:

function img_move(x,y) {
  img.move(x,y); // here
}

img is not defined and if I instatiate again img I would have to remove the insert img and append another with new x,y, right?

Comment: what is `img` in your code ? It isn't defined in your example so I assumed it was an `Elm` instance defined previously.

Comment: I made an update based on the entire example that should make it fully functionnal

Comment: Yes it is. It's let img = document.createElement("img");

Comment: An `img` element doesn't have a `move` method. You are trying to call the `move` method from the `Elm` prototype on the wrong object. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Even though you made global the var pic. The Elm.prototype.move doesn't work. Until now the only way I found is something like:

```
Elm.prototype.move = function (x,y) {
  let img = document.getElementById("pic1");
  img.style.left = x + "px";
  img.style.top = y + "px";
};

```
Which is merely over DOM and not really about the object.

Comment: What do you mean is doesn't work ???? It's working fine right here https://jsfiddle.net/z8vdr0t1/

Comment: Yeah, But wait. You're doing all in the 1st code run cycle, eg: img_insert(50, 50) , setTimeout(() => img_move(100, 100), 2000)
You've inserted the img and then moved it. After that the page renders.
In my case as I explained: inserted via 1 button and then called again via another button. That's a different scenario.

Ex.: <input type="button" value="Insert" onclick="img_insert(100,100);">
  <input type="button" value="Move" onclick="img_move(500,500);">

Comment: Understood and thanks. But not trying to be pick, In case I use and external js file and not embedded as your example I had to do a few things in order to make it happen:
1st the global vars: var pic; var Elm; var img; on top of the .js file then on the prototype.move method the 'this' could be used only over Elm, but img.style.left without 'this' ...

Comment: That's a bit obscure for me. It works though, but I thing 'this' keyword inside a particular method, refers to the method on which it's being called . In the example, it's called by Elm.prototype.move, so 'this' is related to Elm, and img cannot be accessed using 'this' .... a bit confusing ... is that right?

Comment: @GakkiRez Did you notice the `this.img = document.createElement("img");`?

Comment: As we are working with a prototype method, the `this` actually refer to the instance of the Elm object.
I moved the code in a script tag rather that the JS file in JSFiddle because I'm not familiar with JSFiddle and didn't want to bother with import order for the JS file.

Comment: Oh, all the code in my Elm.prototype.insert was without the 'this'. ex: img = document.createElement("img"); 
I added the 'this' and now it works just fine. But, it's not very clear for me yet. I'll do some debugging and step in and inspect the 'this' keyword inside each of the methods to better understand the object. Thanks for now.

Comment: I'll keep coding and debugging in order to have those concepts clear. Thanks Morphyish and Bergi !!!